# How does one find equation of a line in a hyperbolic plane (Poincare disc)?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry

I want to understand the equation of a line through two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the poincare half-disc plane defined as $\mathcal{H} = \left\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 < 1\right\}$, i.e. set of points inside the unit circle.

I'm told that a line in $\mathcal{H}$ is either a diameter $ax+by = 0$ or the arc of a circle that intersects the unit circle at right angles, with an equation $x^2+y^2+2dx+2ey+1=0$ where $d^2+e^2 >1$.

I haven't really been given an example of how this works. How does one determine for example the lines between $z_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $z_2 = \frac{1}{2}i$ or see if they lie on a diameter or not?

EDIT: Is it $x = \Re(z_1)$, $y= \Im (z_1)$ and $x = \Re(z_2)$, $y= \Im (z_2)$ and we just plug these to the given equations? I think I'm starting to sort of understand if that's the case, but I'd still appreciate some explanation. Thanks.

Comment: If your points lie on a diameter, that's your line. Otherwise, the center of the circle you want is on the perpendicular bisector between $z_1$ and $z_2$. The orthogonality of the circles means the center also likes on the line $2z\cdot z_1=1-|z_1|^2$. Where these lines intersect is the center of your orthogonal circle.

Comment: It's easy enough to see that those two points do not lie on a diameter: the radii through those two points meet at right angles at the point $(0,0)$. As for finding $d$ and $e$, just plug in $(x,y) = (1/2,0)$ and $(x,y) = (0,1/2)$, you'll get two linear equations in the two unknowns $d,e$ which you can easily solve for.

Comment: Many may find the following laughable, but the way I do it is to transfer the situation to the Upper Half Plane, where it’s comparatively easy to find the hyperbolic line joining two points. Once I do that, I go back to the disk. I do like @LeeMosher’s suggestion better.

Comment: If you want to do some kind of analytic geometry in the hyperbolic plane, I find the Minkowski hyperboloid model usually the best. It is just like modelling a sphere as $(x,y,z)$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, but now we have $z^2-x^2-y^2=1, z>0$. The line between two points is simply the set of all the linear combinations of these two points which belong to the hyperboloid. Poincaré disk model is great for making pictures, but rarely good for computations. (And it is very easy to map from the hyperboloid model to the Poincaré disk model, it is just a stereographic projection.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone.